# jQuery bind event with function: pass parameters to user function in a better way?

Tags: jquery, function, events, parameter-passing

I want to bind an element with a function with parameters using jQuery's click(). Then I need to call the function directly at some point. This is what I am doing currently:

```
function f1(e){
  f(e.data.a, e.data.b, e.data.c);
}

function f(a, b, c){
  //...
}
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
$('#someElement').click({a: a, b: b, c: c}, f1); //bind function
f(a, b, c); //call directly
```

I find it redundant as I have lots of functions like this. I believe that there are better ways to achieve this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could use data attributes to get the parameters for each element you'll click

HTML

```
<div class="someElement" data-a="1" data-b="2" data-c="3"></div>
<div class="someElement" data-a="4" data-b="5" data-c="6"></div>
```

JS

```
function f(a, b, c) {
  alert(a + " " + b + " " + c);
}

$('.someElement').click(function() {
  var a = $(this).attr('data-a'),
    b = $(this).attr('data-b'),
    c = $(this).attr('data-c');
    f(a, b, c);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call directly your function like this

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
$('#someElement').bind("click",function(){
    f(a, b, c); //call directly
});
```

Comment: This does not work if value of a, b, c is changing dynamically, say inside a for-loop where a,b,c are different in each loop. I found that when calling f(), values of a b c stays at the lastest loop.

Comment: I think it's normal, when you use your for-loop, a,b,c are changing values. When you click on your element, your function is call with the last values taken by a,b,c. Even if you bind an event many times, it's only the last bind event is taken in account

Comment: Does it mean that I have to use 2 functions f & f1, in order to handle for-loops?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle ?